# S3 file is corrupted when using putObject

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to put and object into my s3 bucket using this data returned from my Sagemaker endpoint.

`<Buffer 50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 00 08 00 6c 83 85 50 2c 2e dd 02 9e 61 93 00 fa 7f a1 00 32 00 00 00 6f 75 74 70 75 74 2f 61 75 64 69 6f 5f 66 69 6c 65 5f 31 35 ... > }`

The put request to s3 works perfectly. The file size is as expected, 18mb. However, when I try to play the mp3 link inside the browser, or download the file to play, it says the file it gives me this error:

`This file isn't playable. That might be because the file type is unsupported, the file extension is incorrect, or the file is corrupt.`

Here is my putObject function:

```
var params = {
    Bucket : 'musicbucket-audio-uploads',
    Key : 'test.wav',
    Body : data.Body, //This is the Buffer Data
    ContentType: 'audio/wav'
};
s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
     if (err) console.log('PutObject Error: ' + err); 
     else     console.log(data);          
});
```

I think I'm doing a step incorrectly in my params for `putObject`, but unsure what it is. Could someone please help me spot my mistake?

Comment: I think MP3 content type is audio/mpeg, not audio/wav.

Comment: I've tried switching the ContentType to audio/mpeg and key to .mp3, however the file is still not playing for some reason. Could it be that I need to do an extra step to the ```Body```?

Comment: I've checked to see if the content type of the s3  file was being saved as audio/mpeg, so now I really have no clue why it's not working :/

Comment: It doesn't look like a WAV file. The first 4 bytes would be RIFF. If you store the buffer received from SageMaker to local disk (ignoring S3) is it a valid audio file?

Comment: The ContentType that the SageMaker model I'm using accepts only ```application/x-recordio-protobuf``` and the Buffer above is what I received as output. Currently trying to write it to a lambda function to see if that works

Comment: The SageMaker model presumably has some docs or a specification. What does it say about the format of the returned buffer? It seems pointless to include S3 in this conversation until you understand what you have.

Comment: Yep you're 100% correct! It was a .zip file...that you have to extract to get the ```.wav```. Thanks for the help debugging couldn't have figured it out alone seriously..Really appreciate it lol

Comment: Nice! I should have recognized the header beginning with PK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial bytes of your file don't match the WAV fie format (RIFF) and don't look like an MP3. It must be some other file format. I would check SageMaker model docs or a specification - what does it say about the format of the returned buffer?

Update: seems that it's a ZIP file. Note that `50 4b` hex bytes are `PK` (for Phil Katz, the creator of the original ZIP compression format).